# copy one object data to another object of te same type c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, deep-copy

Well I understand that this is a problem that's been written already and I followed several of the explanations but I still seem to have no luck. Maybe there is a explanation I failed to see during my search or I am doing something slightly wrong.

I have created a graph and I am trying to copy the data from one graph to another graph. This much works. However I am having trouble making them separate.

```
graph_maker temp_graph;
temp_graph = kruskal_graph;
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < min_edges.size(); j++){
    temp_graph.add_undirected_edge(min_edges[j].node1, min_edges[j].node2, min_edges[j].edge_dist);
    if(check_cycle(temp_graph) == true)
        temp_graph = kruskal_graph;
    else
        kruskal_graph = temp_graph;
}
```

the `temp_graph` and `kruskal_graph` is the same type called `graph_maker`. When I conduct the `add_undirected_edge()` function the edge is being added to both objects. In order to keep them separate I have tried overloading the assignment operator for `graph_maker` class:

```
    graphmaker& operator=(const graphmaker& Other)
    {
      v_map = Other.v_map;
      return *this;
    }
```

the `v_map` is the structure containing the data that i need. I have also tried the following:

```
    graphmaker& operator=(graphmaker other)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(v_map, other.v_map);
        return *this;
    }
```

But neither of these techniques are keeping the two objects separate. For both when i add edge the it adds to both for the first line after the for loop. I feel like i am making some simple mistake but i am having a difficult time finding out why.

Thank you for your input.

edit:

```
struct vertex
{
        vector <pair<float,vertex*>> adj; //cost of edge, destination vertex
        string name;
        vertex(string s){
            name=s;
        }
};

class graphmaker
{
    public:
        /*
        graphmaker& operator=(graphmaker other)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(v_map, other.v_map);
            // repeat for other member variables;
            return *this;
        }*/

        graphmaker& operator=(const graphmaker& Other)
        {
          v_map = Other.v_map;
          return *this;
        }

        //typedef map<string, vertex *> map;
        map<string, vertex *> v_map;
        void add_vertex(const string&);
        void add_directed_edge(const string& from, const string& to, float cost);
        void add_undirected_edge(const string& node1, const string& node2, float cost);
        void make_graph(const string& name);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deep-copy a complex data structure containing dynamically allocated elements, you need to initalize every dynamic member with `new` to keep them separate. Therefore, if you have some node(vertex) pointers, they need to be initialized with `new` for the new object.

Comment: When you say every dynamic member with new. For this case it would just be v_map, Would that be correct? My graph is currently a map (v_map) of vertexes and each of my vertex contains the vertex name and a vector of pairs that contain the connected destination vertex and the weight.

Comment: @user2427671, yes, you need to initialize all vertex pointers in v_map with new, then you can constrcut member adj using these new pointers.